# C++ unsigned long and <

Tags: c++, unsigned-long-long-int

I have the following code:

```
while( int()(uStartFrame - iFrameOffset) < 1)
{
    iFrameOffset--;
}
```

uStartFrame and iFrameOffset are both unsigned long, so the < statement is a little difficult, I think.
However, I thought that I fixed it using int().
But the loop runs infinitively, so I guess it doesn't work.

Can somebody help?

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you cast (should be (int) by that way) them? Since they are the same type it does not matter.

Comment: What is this loop intended to achieve? (I'm guessing that `iFrameOffset` is initialy greater than `uStartFrame`?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while( uStartFrame < iFrameOffset + 1)
{
    iFrameOffset--;
}
```

Or even better

```
if(uStartFrame < iFrameOffset + 1)
    iFrameOffset = uStartFrame - 1;
```

The last line also shows the possible error. If `uStartFrame` is `0`, then there's no `unsigned long` variable `x` that can fulfil `uStartFrame == x + 1`.

Comment: I think you misread my code. I am querying if (uStartFrame-iFrameOffset) <1 not (uStartFrame < iFrameOffset) <1

Comment: `a - b < 1` is true if and only if `a < b + 1` is true. That's basic math.

Comment: @zeta: or even `iFrameOffset = std::min(iFrameOffset, uStartFrame - 1);`

Answer (score 1):

The cast is wrong, you should cast it like this,

```
(int)(uStartFrame - iFrameOffset) < 1
```

but this C-style cast is not really C++ style, in your case a `static_cast` is preferable:

```
static_cast<int>(uStartFrame - iFrameOffset) < 1
static_cast<unsigned long>(uStartFrame - iFrameOffset) < 1
```

Apart from that, when you write `int()(x)` you define a function that returns an integer and accepts no parameters, and then invoke it with uStartFrame - iFrameOffset as an argument. It shouldn't even compile, well at least gcc 4.8 rightfully complains about this.

Your compiler obviously does compile it and maybe even wrongly treats it as a function that returns an un-initialized integer, most likely 0, and that possible explains why your loop runs forever.

Answer (score 0):

You're casting the test (uStartFrame-iFrameOffset) into int, not the iFrameOffset. So, if the iFrameOffset is big (max could be 2^64-1 - or bigger depending on system), then you might need 2^64 loops to get to the end.

This could be as much as a giga seconds. So, you should rethink this loop. It's not a goo idea.